# How to fix field collection ajax #edit-submit clash with node #edit-submit?

Tags: ajax, entities

I have Drupal 7.41, field_collection 7.x-1.0-beta10+1-dev, and field_collection_ajax 7.x-1.x-dev

I am the admin of a site where we have a disease content type, and a part of each disease node is its lab tests. (Some diseases have upwards of 400+ lab tests) I use Field Collection to format the lab tests, and I use Field Collection Ajax to display them in an way that makes them easier to work with when there are many lab tests.

Field Collection Ajax uses ajax to display, edit, and save the individual field collection items. The "Save Item to List" button for Field Collection Ajax appears to be getting mixed up with the node save button. They both have the same id #edit-submit. I don't know for certain, but it appears that on the disease nodes that have 400+ lab tests after you edit a lab test, the next time you try to save another field collection item to the list it acts like you are trying to save the node, and the next time you try to save the node it acts like you are trying to save a field collection item.

Does anyone have any experience with this happening with field_collection_ajax and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that that large node was hitting the max_input_vars cealing. So I just had to increase that and it worked.